# Why is the term not squared in the antigen-antibody interaction formula?

Tags: kinetics

From [Antigen-antibody interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigen-antibody_interaction) (Wikipedia):

[image]

We've basically multiplied two similar terms, because inverted Kd is Ka - why isn't there any square signs (power of two)?

Comment: Why would you expect there to be squared terms?

Comment: @CurtF. - we're multiplying two similar terms, as my last sentence says. `[AbAg]*[AbAg] =  [AbAg]^2`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Wikipedia is just wrong.

Comment: I edited Wikipedia to correct the problem.

Comment: @CurtF. - thank you! I also wonder why we multiply [Ab]*[Ag] and not, say sum them up, but I should try to read up on this first.